# Where can I download Ubuntu logo assets?

Tags: community

Is there a link where people can get something like an official ubuntu logo assets kit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the brand assets are on [design.ubuntu.com](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/).

- [Logos](http://design.canonical.com/brand/Logos/)